# 4294A Binary .DAT File to excel file

Tags: excel, matlab

I used the Precision Impedance Analyzer Agilent 4294A producing a binary file.
I do matlab to rewrite the file to excel file.

```
fid = fopen('myfile.DAT','r');
data = fread(fid,inf,'*uint8');
```

I have tried every kinds of encode formate,but the data just like garbled text.
The machine manual only describes the data format as the picture saying.
Could anyone help me
Thank you in advance.
[image: the manual describe]

Comment: It's garbled even when you output to a .txt format?

Comment: Yes, the binary transform to txt should know the encode,but I don't know what is it

Comment: Can't you output directly to a .txt file instead of to a binary file that you need to transform?

Comment: Can you use an on line converter like this? https://toolsocean.com/binary-to-text